# Rails has_many association how to guarantee only one of each associated record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have this system essentially:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tag_associations
  has_many :tags, through :tag_associations
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  # attr :name
end
```

How do I make it so the article can only have one of each tag name? That is, say I have these tags:

```
{ name: 'foo' }
{ name: 'bar' }
{ name: 'baz' }
```

I would eexpect this to be the final result:

```
tag1 = Tag.create!(name: 'foo')
tag2 = Tag.create!(name: 'bar')
tag3 = Tag.create!(name: 'baz')
article.tags << tag1
article.tags << tag2
article.tags << tag1
article.tags << tag1
article.tags << tag1
article.save!
article.tags # => [tag1, tag2]
```

How do I achieve this? I am not highly familiar with Rails paradigms, and am not really sure how to do this in a general way even with plain SQL. But I am just looking for how to do this the Rails way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done using an ActiveRecord uniqueness validation.

In this case, I would suggest that the validation should be applied in the `ArticleTag` model. Create this model if you don't already have it.

```rb
class ArticleTag < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :tag_id, :uniqueness, scope: :article_id

end
```

This says that instances of ArticleTag with associated with a given Article should have unique tag_id. So if you try to create a duplicate tag for an articl, you'll raise a validation error.